# stop location when hide app

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I created a view. In the view I did function - measurement of the distance from the user to the marker on the map. But when the user turns the application remains a warning that my application uses geolocation. How do I remove the warning? I'm trying to stop the geolocation when the user turns the application. I found this method: applicationWillEnterForeground.But very few examples of it. I try do something like this

```
if(&UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification) { //needed to run on older devices, otherwise you'll get EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(enteredForeground:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}
```

However, this code leaves the warning , it turns off the warning only if you click on it.
Tell me how can I stop location when the application is hide?

PS in info.plist i add

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```

it is example of warning

[image]

part of my code

```
-(void)setupArray{   
    self.myLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.myLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [self.myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    self.myLocationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    CLLocation *startLocation = self.myLocationManager.location;
    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:60.050043 longitude:30.345783];
     float betweenDistance=[startLocation distanceFromLocation:location];
    [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"###"];
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:59.93 longitude:30.35 zoom:9];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
    mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = true;
    mapView_.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    mapView_.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
    mapView_.center = self.view.center;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:mapView_];
```

**UPDATE**
if i write this is appdelegate

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog("app hide"); //it's work
}
```

but if i write this in my view where i wrote propety CCLocation it's not work. I don't understand where I need to enter `[myLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation];`

Answer (score 1):

You try to deal with the wrong app state change — `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` is posted when your app is about to **become active**, i.e. will transfer from background to foreground. Use the `- applicationWillResignActive:` method in your AppDelegate or subscribe for `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` and stop your geolocation services.

P.S. Your code sure needs some cleanup, no need for `self.myLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];` and `[self.myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];` multiple calls. You also should use underscore character before instance variable name — `_mapView` instead of `mapView_`. Good luck!

Comment: i know that my code is not cool, it is my second app. In AppDelegete i need to write something like this? - `(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
NSLog(@"applicationWillResignActive");
}`

Comment: No, you should call the `CLLocationManager`'s `- stopUpdatingLocation` method. You should do it in the same class where you have your `myLocationManager` property. Since iOS 8 you can also request "only when in use" location services authorization — so, if you don't plan to support older iOS versions you can just opt in for this behavior and save some time for reading about notifications, methods and coding in general.

Comment: please look on my question - i apdate this

Comment: You need to read about the [notifications](http://www.devfright.com/nsnotificationcenter-tutorial/). The system posts them when it changes state and in a bunch of other occasions. You subscribe to the ones you're interested in and the appropriate method gets called.